# Does docker on windows use a windows virtual machine to create a windows container?

Tags: windows, docker, build, devops

The software I build is written for windows and built on windows.
Right now I am in the process of finding a solution to isolate my build environments.
I am comparing two options - using virtual machines and using containers. I am also considering the issue of performance.
Unfortunately windows docker containers can only be run from windows.
Do windows containers run faster than windows virtual machines?
Does docker on windows use a virtual machine to host a windows container?

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Containerization and Virtualization have a lot in common but have different architectural designs. So you should rather try to invest some time and think about the things you want to do. Or you should specify your question and tell us what your main goal is.

Maybe you should check out this https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/containers-vs-vms and this https://www.edureka.co/blog/docker-for-windows/

Comment: I am already very familiar with docker under linux and the difference between virtualization and containerization. I just want to know - is windows docker container faster than a VM with windows installed? Does docker desktop uses a windows VM to create a windows container?

Comment: To you´re questions:
  - is windows docker container faster than a VM with windows installed? Answer: Docker containers are generally faster and less resource-intensive than virtual machines. 
  - Does docker desktop uses a windows VM to create a windows container? Answer: It enables the Hyper-V module and creates a VM depending on which OS System you need to have in the container

Comment: If docker on Windows uses a VM for hosting a Windows container, how can it be faster than a VM?